# Output NodeJS / MongoDB Query to String Runnable in Console

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In NodeJS, I have an aggregate MongoDB query with ObjectIDs. I'm simply trying to output the query to a string (e.g. console.log) so that I can copy/paste it into a console and run the query manually.

I can't find any method on the query itself so I'm doing a console.log on the pipeline json.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(pipeline));
```

Which outputs:

```
[{"$match":{"$and":[{"users.userId":{"$eq":{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"type":"Buffer","data":[93,151,104,127,56,207,132,25,197,44,232,49]}}}},{"users.userId":{"$eq":{"_bsontype":"ObjectID","id":{"type":"Buffer","data":[93,151,104,127,56,207,132,25,197,44,232,49]}}}}]}}]
```

This is the result I'm hoping for which runs successfully in the console:

````
[{"$match":{"$and":[{"users.userId":{"$eq":ObjectId("5d97687f38cf8419c52ce831")}},{"users.userId":{"$eq":ObjectId("5d97687f38cf8419c52ce831")}}]}}]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **native client of mongodb for node.js** then,

Going by the official docs of mongodb client for node
( http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/reference/connecting/connection-settings/ ),

You can use **"loggerLevel"** connection option for mongodb, to print the queries.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:50000,localhost:50001';
// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// create a client, passing in additional options
// loggerLevel: debug will print all query on the console
const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  poolSize: 10, tls: true
  loggerLevel: debug 
});

// Use connect method to connect to the server
client.connect(function(err) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});
```

else If you are using any ORM for mongoDB such as mongoose (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) then,

using mongoose.set('debug', true) will print the queries on the console,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { mongo, env } = require('./vars')

// Exit application on error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`MongoDB connection error: ${err}`)
  process.exit(-1)
})

// print mongoose logs in dev env
if (env === 'development') {
  mongoose.set('debug', true)
}

/**
* Connect to mongo db
*/
const connect = async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(mongo.uri, {
    socketTimeoutMS: 60000,
    keepAlive: true,
    useMongoClient: true,
    reconnectTries: 60000,
    poolSize: 10
  })
  return mongoose.connection
}

exports.connect = connect
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is IDs are stored as BSON which clearly had a distinct serializer. If you want to have these serialize in a way compatible with the MongoDB command line, you'd need a custom serializer to convert the ID values.

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has a `replacer` function you can apply to each key, I can't test this right now but I presume this would work:

```
JSON.stringify(pipeline, (k, v) => {
  if (k === '$eq') {
    return v.toString()
  }
  return v;
})
```

This wouldn't give you `ObjectId('...')` just the value directly (which I think should be fine).